# How to use max-aspect-ratio with Sass using fraction as a variable?

Tags: variables, sass, media-queries, fractions

How can I use a fraction in a variable with SASS language ?
This code works :

```
div{
    @media screen and  (max-aspect-ratio: 54/25) {
       width:100%;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't works ( it compiles, but $var seems to be equal 0 ):

```
$var: 54/25;

div{
    @media screen and  (max-aspect-ratio: $var) {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

When I use mixin I get the same weird issue.

```
// THIS MIXIN IS WORKING
@mixin media-maxAspectRatio() {
    @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 54/25) {
        &{ @content; }
    }
}

$breakpoints: (
    "mobileWidth": 500px,
    "fraction": 54/25
);

// THIS MIXIN IS NOT WORKING calling "fraction" as $_key 
@mixin media-maxAspectRatio($_key) {
    @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: map-get($breakpoints, $_key)) 
    {
        &{ @content; 
         }
    }
}
```

It's weird to seems to work with px values but with fraction I 
get this not working. Maybe it's the / character ?
More generally what's the best way to use sass variables with media queries and specially max-aspect-ratio and min-aspect-ratio.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the aspect ratio as a string, otherwise Sass will compile the expression as a mathematical opetation, printing `2.16` instead of `54/25`. Sass will print it unquoted when compiled.

```
$breakpoints: (
    "mobileWidth": 500px,
    "fraction": "54/25"
);

@mixin media-maxAspectRatio($_key) {
    @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: map-get($breakpoints, $_key)) {
      @content; 
    }
}
```

Check the working example [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/55f67de3a42c92b5f24326d2f8b3ff3a)

Comment: Thanks , this is the answer :-)